# Finding list of empty Strings in entire application

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Ours is an enterprise application which has 5000+ java classes which are coded by many developers over span of 15 years. What I am currently trying to find in this code is usage of String declarations with empty values. i.e `String myName =""` which should actually have been `String myName = null`. As far as I understand empty String declarations is nothing but String object creation without the usage of keyword new which adds the object in the heap along with String constant pool.

Those 5000 classes are modularized into separate projects and I want to find all these declarations where String is declared with `""` instead of `null`

Is there anyway to achieve this using Pattern or Matcher class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to find in source code, you can use any IDE with regex search. The pattern is something like: `String\s+\w+\s*=\s*""`.

Comment: just exactly what I needed... I went through the switches in the above example and now found that it was so trivial to find it if you know the API... Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure replacing all Strings without thinking a good idea?

Consider this piece of code:

```
String myName ="";
If (anycondition) {
  myName = "somevalue"
}
if (myName.startsWith("something") ) 
{
  ...
}
```

Get ready for some NullpointerExceptions...

Comment: yeah, you are absolutely right. It will lead to NPE's but we can handle them instead of bloating unecessary String objects.